two java repositories one with dependency code and the other with the application code, how do i containerise this app?
Here is my question or problem I am facing in detail.
I have two git repositories which have multiple branches, dev branches and master, first is a java application(repo1) and the other java repository that creates dependency jars(repo2) in ".m2" directory after "mvn clean install", for repo1 to be successfully built jars from repo2 are required which then can be deployed in tomcat.
I want to containerise this application in repo1. I have created the dockerfile which can build the application if there are both repositories in the context directory and create a docker image that can be deployed.
But the problem is I am unable to create a Jenkins job which can pull both repositories when there is any change in either of them and trigger the build.
I've tried a pipeline job which can take in a jenkinsfile, it polls both SCMs and triggers the job if there is a change in either of the repos, but it can only be done for a single branch. As I meantioned earlier I have multiple branches and I can't create a job for each one of those branches and cretae more whenever there is a new branch, because of it this is not a feasible option.
I've also tried a multibranch job, this will build for multiple branches but it can only check for changes in only one repo since it is not built for checking different code bases but multiple repositories with same code base(it's a different topic). The take from this was it will not check for the changes in both repositories.
What I am looking for is a setup which will check for any change in all branches of both repositories and if found trigger a build that will pull changes and create the docker image.
So this is the issue, and I am not getting any solution for this problem. Please let me know if anyone had the same issue and found a solution.
PS: I hope the information I've given is enough and if not do let me know and I'll provide anything needed.
Thanks in advance.

So, if there is a new commit in some branch in repo2, which commit from repo1 are you going to check out?

@Iterokun if there is a new commit in a branch "somebranch" in repo2, I'll check out the latest commit in the "somebranch" in repo1, if "somebranch" does not exist in repo1 then the latest commit of the master branch of repo1.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The solution I went ahead with is building both repo1 and repo2 outside the docker, and in Dockerfile only copying the final .war and .jar files into the tomcat image. This way I don't have to worry about the dependencies from repo2 in .m2 directory, because both the repos are being built on the same host.
But the only drawback is that if I want to run it on a different host, I must manually set up the environment like installing the maven, java, etc.

The question was more about triggering builds, not how they are arranged on the agent. Your answer doesn't clarify that.

I understand what you are saying, but I needed a way to achieve a setup where I can get a tomcat image with my built .jar and .war files in it and this method works. It looks like a workaround but it does the job.

This is why we do monorepos. But since you don't have one you will have to pay the price of dependency tracking: in repo1 you will have a reference to a specific version of your repo2 dependency (be it a commit hash or a semver of an artifact - doesn't matter). Then you will need only one trigger - for repo1, since any updates to repo2 would have a corresponding version update in repo1.

so I should manually pull repo1 when there is a change in repo2 using the commit hash, this means i have to setup a multibranch only for repo2, but if there is any change in repo1 it will be ignored and a build won't be triggered, but i want to trigger the build if change found in either repos

When there is a change in repo2 you would do nothing, since that new version is not used in repo1 yet and generally speaking there is no way to tell where it might be used. "The latest commit from a branch with the same name" is not a widely supported convention, so Jenkins has no provisions for it.

what if the commit in repo2(dependency) is to fix the bug in repo1(app) which happens after the commit in repo1. This is something to be considered as well. In the meantime I'll setup a multibranch that checks for changes in repo1 and does nothing if anything is changed in repo2, I'll try this and update the results.

And what would make repo1 use the fix in repo2? This "latest commit" kind of dependency tracking is amateurish. It might work for a small scale slow paced development, but as complexity grows you would want control.

Thank you for the help, I tried the solution you suggested but I have other scenarios where it could become a problem, so I went ahead with the solution I posted below.
